# classname[i].length returns undefined in console and more errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-development-server

```js
"use strict";

const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
const showModal = document.querySelector(".buttons");
const xModal = document.querySelector(".close-modal");
console.log(showModal.length);

const openModal = function() {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  console.log("opened");
};

const closeModal = function() {
  modal.classList.add("hidden");
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
};

for (let i = 0; i < showModal.length; i++)
  showModal[i].addEventListener("click", openModal);

xModal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Escape" && !modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    closeModal();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css " />
  <title>Modal Window</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 3</button>

  <div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <h2>This is a Modal Window</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code, the click event wasn't working. After checking it a couple of times, I saw that the "console.log(showModal.length);" returns undefined, instead of returning a number and it also says the variable "i" is undefined. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` returns a single HTMLElement matching the selector. You want `document.querySelectorAll` which returns an array of all elements matching the selector.

```
const showModal = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
```

```js
"use strict";

const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
const showModal = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
const xModal = document.querySelector(".close-modal");
console.log(showModal.length);

const openModal = function() {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  console.log("opened");
};

const closeModal = function() {
  modal.classList.add("hidden");
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
};

for (let i = 0; i < showModal.length; i++)
  showModal[i].addEventListener("click", openModal);

xModal.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Escape" && !modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    closeModal();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css " />
  <title>Modal Window</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 3</button>

  <div class="modal hidden">
    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
    <h2>This is a Modal Window</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
</body>

</html>
```